# Getting more data from messages.get in C#

Tags: gmail-api

I'm having trouble getting more than just the snippet for text data for the message I am trying to retrieve using the Gmail API. Here is the piece of test code I am working with:

```
    public string GetMail()
    {
        GmailService service = (GmailService)HttpContext.Current.Session["service"];

        Message messageFeed = service.Users.Messages.List("me").Execute().Messages.First();

        UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest getReq = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest(service, "me", messageFeed.Id);

        getReq.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full;
        Message message = getReq.Execute();

        return message.Raw;
    }
```

For some reason, when I call message.Raw, it is returning null. I am able to retrieve other properties as what the format=minimal setting would based off of the API playground example I was playing with.

However in my code, I am setting the format enum to "full", yet I am still unable to retrieve the full data of the message.

Am I completely missing something here?

Comment: GmailService in ***Session*** ? low performance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing up formats and response types.  If you want the raw message as a string in Message.raw then you need to set:

```
getReq.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
```

If you want the parsed message back (in the "payload" field) then you can use getReq.Format of Full like you have.

Acceptable values are:

- "full": Returns the parsed email message content in the payload field and the raw field is not used. (default)
- "minimal": Only returns email message metadata such as identifiers and labels, it does not return the email headers, body, or payload.
- "raw": Returns the entire email message content in the raw field as a string and the payload   field is not used. This includes the identifiers, labels, metadata, MIME structure, and small   body parts (typically less than 2KB).

from: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: Can you parse in classes C# the ***raw*** ?