# How to get Gmail subjects using Gmail API in C#

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I am making an app that can get all the e-mails in Gmail Inbox from a C# console application.

I have this code below that prints out the console the email body contents:

```
UsersResource.ThreadsResource.ListRequest threadRequest = service.Users.Threads.List("me");
IList<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Thread> threads = threadRequest.Execute().Threads;

foreach(var thread in threads)
{
     //print gmail body content
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", thread.Snippet);
}
```

So how do I get gmail subjects instead?
Any contribution will be appriciated!

Comment: This question asked before , please check this thread : [how-to-retrieve-my-gmail-messages-using-gmail-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448193/how-to-retrieve-my-gmail-messages-using-gmail-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string GetMail(){
GmailService service = (GmailService)HttpContext.Current.Session["service"];
Message messageFeed = service.Users.Messages.List("me").Execute().Messages.First();
UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest getReq = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest(service, "me", messageFeed.Id);
 //"raw": Returns the full email message data with body content in the raw field as a base64url encoded string; the payload field is not used. 
getReq.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
 Message message = getReq.Execute();
return message.Raw;
}
```

[[Getting more data from messages.get in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442490/getting-more-data-from-messages-get-in-c-sharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442490/getting-more-data-from-messages-get-in-c-sharp)

[Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

Better solution:

[Read the Gmail Inbox Feed with .NET and OAuth](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.tr/2011/09/read-gmail-inbox-feed-with-net-and.html)